# Flask with Python - How can I display a card with information from database when a button is clicked

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to display at the bottom of a webpage, a message or a card, like the description of an item when user clicks a submit button

My Python code looks like this:

```
@app.route("/factpage", methods=["GET","POST"])
def enterfruit():
    if request.method == "POST":
        fruit = request.form.get("fruitname")
        username = session["username"]
        db.execute("insert into fruits(username, fruit) values (?,?)", username, fruit);
        desc = db.execute("select description from fruitinfo where fruit=?", fruit)
        flash("Thank you for entering " + fruit + "!")
        return render_template("factpage.html")
        # how can I display this description(desc) as a card at the bottom of the page??

    else:
        return render_template("factpage.html")
```

I tried to add this in factpage.html, but it is not displaying:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Quote
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
            <p>{{ desc }}</p>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: can you add your python code all the way to your render_template?

Comment: Please also fix your code. Currently you don't have a close paren `)` after the `@app.route` decorator arguments.

Comment: @FLSte   I have added the render_template. Could you please check and suggest how I can reference the card in the code?  I want the flash function and the card to display at the same time.

Comment: Thank you @MattDMo I made the change. That was a mistake when I copied it as a question here

Answer (score 0):

```
flash("Thank you for entering " + fruit + "!")
return render_template("factpage.html", desc=desc)
```

[render_template()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.render_template) can take multiple arguments.  The first is the html file/string of "static" code you would like to show.  Any following keyword arguments are passed to the jinja templating to be used in rendering the final html.  In this case, while `desc` was a variable in your python code it was not available to be used by the jinja templating.